# Create DataGrid from list of object

Tags: c#, grid, uwp

I have these two classes:

```
public class FrigoriferoClass
{
    public int codice { get; set; }
    public string contenuto { get; set; }
    public int tempMin { get; set; }
    public int tempMax { get; set; }
    public List<ControlloClass> controllo { get; set; }

    public FrigoriferoClass(int cod, string cont, int min, int max)
    {
        controllo = new List<ControlloClass>();
        codice = cod;
        contenuto = cont;
        tempMin = min;
        tempMax = max;
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class ControlloClass
{
    public int temp { get; set; }
    public DateTime data { get; set; }

    public ControlloClass(int t, DateTime d)
    {
        temp = t;
        data = new DateTime();
        data = d;
    }
}
```

I created a list of `FrigoriferoClass` and with some of their data I want to create a grid.
I want the grid to look like this (I made it on excel only for example):

[image: Example]

And after that I need to create a `pdf` file with this grid.

I tried to use syncfusion, but I don't know how to make a grid in this way.

Anyone can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
using Syncfusion.XlsIO;
using Syncfusion.Pdf;
using Syncfusion.ExcelToPdfConverter;
...

// in a method
using (Stream readFile = stream for excel file)
{
    ExcelToPdfConverter converter = new ExcelToPdfConverter(readFile);
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument();
    // set Your setting You like
    ExcelToPdfConverterSettings settings = new ExcelToPdfConverterSettings();
    settings.TemplateDocument = pdfDoc;
    settings.DisplayGridLines = GridLinesDisplayStyle.Invisible;
    pdfDoc = converter.Convert(settings);
    pdfDoc.Save("ExceltoPDF.pdf", Response, HttpReadType.Save);
    readFile.Close();
}
```

Comment: I have red underscore on DataTable, I need to using some references?

Comment: Ohh... uwp. Didn't check the tags. Btw I have changed the answer to use first column as it should be. I'll check how to convert it into ObservableCollection...

Comment: But if I can't use DataTable, how can I solve my problem?

Comment: @AndreaCocci it needs a little tweaking. At least in WPF id doesn't show the rows, but the values are there. Can You check if it works for uwp? Or implement IEnumberable on it.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. It show only one column header and empty rows under its in DataGrid.

Comment: @AndreaCocci I have made a new version with reflection

Comment: I have red underscore on AppDomain, AssemblyBuilder, ModuleBuilder, TypeBuilder, PropertyBuilder, MethodBuilder and ILGenerator. I think that this method is not compatible with uwp :(

Comment: @AndreaCocci I have changed the answer, to answer Your second question.Please update the question next time instead.